# jQuery how to remove all <span> tags from a <div>?

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I've tried both of the following but none of them worked:

```
$('#divhtml').remove('span')

$('#divhtml').find('span').remove()
```

**EDIT:** `$('#divhtml').find('span').remove()` worked on 2nd try.

Comment: Just to confirm, one of your `div` has `id="divhtml"`?

Comment: If `$('#divhtml').find('span').remove()` isn't working problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Posting HTML is going to be necessary. `.find('span').remove()` will work isolated so there is something else wrong (I believe).

Comment: The <span> elements are auto-generated by the jquery checkbox tree plugin. for some reason i need to rebind the checkbox tree, and that created weird css issues because everytime i call checkboxtree(), i create another set of <span>s...i wish there was a 'destroy' method for that plugin.

Comment: double checked. remove('span') indeed doesn't work...find('span').remove() worked this time. i'll update my q.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have already used a correct statement:

```
$('#divhtml').find('span').remove()
```

This should work. Please provide more context... See this jsfiddle as "proof" that something else is wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/Pbgqy/

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
$("#divhtml span").remove()
```

Comment: That's the same as `$('#divhtml').find('span').remove()` except that using the `find()` function is faster (no string manipulation necessary).

Comment: I had problems using this format in Internet Explorer. Using find() had no problem.