# Delete all the spans inside div on button click in jquery

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I have below code which displays the bunch of spans elements in my web page

```
 <div id="tags" style="border:none;width:370px;">
   {% for category in AllCategories %}            
   <span class="tag" id="4">{{ category.sname }}</span>
   {% endfor %}
 <div>
```

This is Django notation of fetching data in webpage (python), I have a button which when I click should remove all the spans inside my div (id=tags).

How can I do it in jquery ?

I tried below

```
 $('#tags').on('click','.tag',function(){ 
     $(this).remove();
 });
```

but it doesn't work for all the spans.

Comment: You seem to be creating the same ID in a loop ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `#tags` instead of `#tags1`

Comment: `$("#tags1")` does not exist, so `$(this)` is referring to something other than the spans you are attempting to remove

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.. Its 'tags'

Comment: make sure you are using it `on ready`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery how to remove all <span> tags from a <div>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931955/jquery-how-to-remove-all-span-tags-from-a-div)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your code in question interprets - remove all `spans` when the delegated `click` event is targeted on `.tag`spans, so spans would be removed only when you click on `spans`

Try to use `remove()` :

```js
$(function(){
    $('#tags').on('click', function(){ 
        $(this).find('.tag').remove()
    });
});
```

```css
#tags{
  background-color: green;
}
span{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tags">
  <span class='tag'>Span 1</span><br/>
  <span class='tag'>Span 2</span><br/>
  <span class='tag'>Span 3</span><br/>
  <span class='tag'>Span 4</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Zakaria! am checking now.

Comment: `$('#tags .tag').remove();` is expensive, rather use `find` and already having ref this, so `$(this).find('.tag').remove();`

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
       $('#tags').on('click', function(){ 
         $(this).find('span.tag').remove();
       });
    });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `closest` traverses upwards, use `find` instead as `spans` are inside `div`

Comment: Ya, that was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **detach** method instead of **remove**